# Runtime Error -SIGABRT

Tags: c, runtime-error

```
#toggle the string 

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char S[100],ch;
   int i=0;
   gets(S);
   while((S[i]!='\0')&&(i<100))
   {
       ch=S[i];
       if((ch>='A')&&(ch<='Z'))
           S[i]+=32;
       else if((ch>='a')&&(ch<='z'))
           S[i]-=32;
       i++;
   }
   printf("%s\n",S);
   return 0;
}
```

Please let me know what's wrong with the code ( code is to toggle the string I.e. uppercase to lowercase and vice versa.  I m getting SIGABRT runtime error ...

Comment: Don't use `gets()`; it cannot be used safely.

Comment: `gets` assumes S is infinite in length. You will get an abort if your input cannot be stored in `S` (i.e. if it is larger than 100 characters).

Comment: What input triggers SIGABRT?

Comment: `gets(S);` ==> `fgets(S, sizeof S, stdin);`

Comment: @diciu: "*... larger than*" 99 characters. Mind the `0`-terminator.

Comment: This is the perfect opportunity to learn to use a debugger to trace through the program line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is *really* going on.

Comment: Aside: you should really check `i<100` *before* using it to index `S[100]`. Switching them round you would have `while((i<100)&&(S[i]!='\0'))` and the short-circuit rule would prevent you indexing `S` out of bounds.

Comment: Is there a good reason for not using `isupper()`, `islower()`, `toupper()` and `tolower()`?  At any rate, I can't see a good reason other than abuse of `gets()` for why this would crash.

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. documents why each header file is included
3. will work properly even on non-ASCII character sets (like EBCDIC)
4. eliminates unneeded variables
5. uses valid function call: `fgets()` to read from stdin
6. to exit this program enter: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or (depending on OS) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>

and now the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // fgets(), printf()
#include <ctype.h>  // toupper(), tolower(), isupper(), islower()

int main( void )
{
   char S[100];

   //gets(S);
   if( fgets( S, sizeof( S ), stdin ) )
   {
       for( size_t i=0; S[i]; i++ )
       {
           if( isupper( S[i]) )
               S[i] = (char)tolower( S[i] );

           else if( islower( S[i] ) )
               S[i] = (char)toupper( S[i] );
       }

       printf("%s\n",S);
   }

   return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: In your answers, I do not want to know what your code does. Instead, when answering, why not put a little effort into explaining what went wrong in the OPs code about which he has asked the question. A "here, see my code" answer is only useful if the OP already understands where his defect in logic lay. Otherwise, more times than not, you get nothing but an "OK, I'll do it your way", and no learning has occurred. Why does your code work with non-ASCII? Why do you continue with a capital `S`? Why is `fgets` valid and `gets` not? (when was it removed?) Just a little more effort helps.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin,  Actually, I have a difficult time stating 'why' some posted code does not work.  Especially if I'm not sure I can clearly explain the cause.  Therefore, I often find it more direct to provide an example of (one way) to code the problem.  I usually say my code is 'proposed' because it is only one way it can be done, not the only way.  Also, I feel the OP may be discouraged if I discuss each and every detail of what is 'wrong' with the OPs code. (some of those 'wrong' items may actually be just my opinion about poor coding practice, etc)